# Приложение на C# источник данных phpmyadmin. Можно сделать visual-studio-2010?

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Можно ли сделать постоянным и основным источником данных в приложении на C#, используя БД phpmyadmin? Т.е. я могу сделать таким образом полноценное нужное мне приложение?

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: эмм..а с каких это пор phpmyadmin стал базой данных?

Comment: ну я имею ввиду БД созданную в phpmyadmin!

Comment: phpmyadmin - это всего лишь веб-приложение. Теоретически в нем может быть создана вообще любая бд. Для C# совершенно все равно, в чем вы создавали бд

Comment: А можете посоветовать, где лучше всего создать БД? Просто новичок в этом деле, с С шарп только первый раз столкнулся!

Comment: это сильно зависит от интересующей вас субд

Comment: Мне нужно создать приложение для обмена информации между пользователями. Т.е. пользователь может вносить инфу в БД и также потом смотреть ее. Хочу использовать для этого сервер, на котором нужно создать БД. Если есть варианты получше БД созданной в phpmyadmin, подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @strogan послушайте, я еще раз вам говорю - нет никакой разницы, в чем вы создадите свою бд - хоть руками скрипты напишете - для приложения это неважно. Имеет значение то, какую субд вы выберете. Если вам нужна MySQL, то придется установить для нее поставщик данных. C MS SQL и Oracle можно работать  "искаропки"

Answer (score 1):

[[@strogan](/users/29114/strogan)](/users/29114/strogan), вы создали БД MySQL.

Как вообще работать с БД (пространство имен ADO.NET) в C# можете почитать тут: http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html

Конкретно с MySQL тут: http://csharpprogramming.ru/database/rabota-s-bazoj-dannyx-mysql-v-c

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас ознакомлюсь!

Comment: пытаюсь попробовать сделать все по видео уроку. Столкнулся с проблемой. не могу найти у себя компонент MySql.data при добавлении!

Comment: Пропустил первый урок. Извините:)

Answer (score 0):

Привет . Вторая ссылка которую указал [@strogan](/users/29114/strogan) это то что вам нужно .я сам пишу программу которая привязана к MySQL именно с этого сайта я смог разобраться что к чему . Плюс есть еще один сайт . Так вообще все что надо  . Если бы я его нашел пол года назад когда начал учить программирования то мне не пришлось бы читать кучу ненужной литературы. Если хотите я вам дам ссылку на этот ресурс , когда вернусь домой .

Comment: спасибо... надеюсь, там полезная информация!

Comment: Жду ссылку!